# Software / API to track new concepts or ideas from web searches

Tags: web-browser, search, search-engine, social-networks, google-search

Is there any Software or API of Google,Twitter or other search Engines or Social Networks to track emergent or new concepts/ideas (words) or new combinations, made from the searches in the web, but not necessarily "trendy topics"?

Accepted any suggestion of particular web crawlers, bots, AI, new browsers, API, Software, query languages, graph software, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Google Trends might fit. Alexa.com can do it too. Not just by checking site click changes but I think it actually does what you asked. But you must pay. And they probably focus on trendy topics unless you focus on one specific site or keyword. You may need to lookup SEO and keyword research.